# How to asset a string does NOT contain a regex

Tags: ansible

How do you do the inverse of this?

```
- name: "Checking cluster.name is valid"
  assert:
    that:
      - cluster.name is search('\W')
    fail_msg: "cluster.name can only contain '[a-zA-Z0-9_]'"
```

I want to asset that the cluster.name does not contain any characters from the regexp class '\W'. I can't seem to use stuff like:

```
- cluster.name is not search('\W')
```

I can't do this obviously:

```
- cluster.name is search('\w')
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this several different ways, including with `is not search`.

For example:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: "Checking cluster.name is valid"
      assert:
        that:
          - cluster.name is match('^\w+$')
        fail_msg: "cluster.name can only contain '[a-zA-Z0-9_]'"
      vars:
        - cluster:
            name: foo
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: "Checking cluster.name is valid"
      assert:
        that:
          - cluster.name is not search('\W')
        fail_msg: "cluster.name can only contain '[a-zA-Z0-9_]'"
      vars:
        - cluster:
            name: foo
...
```

The first task asserts that all characters are in `\w`. The second asserts that no characters are in `\W`.

Changing the cluster name to "foo$" results in:

```
TASK [Checking cluster.name is valid] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "cluster.name is match('^\\w+$')", 
    "changed": false, 
    "evaluated_to": false, 
    "msg": "cluster.name can only contain '[a-zA-Z0-9_]'"
}
...ignoring

TASK [Checking cluster.name is valid] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "cluster.name is not search('\\W')", 
    "changed": false, 
    "evaluated_to": false, 
    "msg": "cluster.name can only contain '[a-zA-Z0-9_]'"
}
```

Comment: What version on ansible? (I'm 2.9.0) "is not search" does not work for me. Complains about seeing 'not' where it doesn't expect it. (Sorry in a meeting and don't have access to the hosts)

Comment: @Crashk1d 2.8.3 here.

Comment: This will work though ```cluster.name is match('^\w+$')```. I wasn't aware it supported full regexp.