# Ansible find in path exact filename without regex

Tags: linux, ansible

Using Ansible I am struggling to use the `find` module for an exact filename without using regex.

My use case takes user input and I am worried that the user would try to be clever and use regex to do more than I want to allow them to do.  I could [reject the string if it contains regex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61640287/2031150), but I would rather treat the string as an exact filename.

The code below does find matching files, but if the filename given is `*.txt`, all .txt files will be matched.

```yaml
- name: collect paths for matching file
  find:
    paths: "{{ target_folder }}"
    patterns: "{{ filename }}"
    file_type: file
    recurse: true
  register: file_matches
```

The reason I am worried about the impact of rejecting particular strings is that I know that, in rare cases, some of the filenames that are going to be looked at have non-ASCII characters, and I don't know how that will play with a no-regex assert.

Comment: There is a `regex_escape` filter that seems to achieve just what you want: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions

Comment: I have found that if I change the patterns line to `patterns: "{{ filename | regex_escape() }}"` that it does indeed no longer match all txt files with *.txt, but it also no longer matches any filename given.

Comment: Probably because the dot is escaped too. Mind that, per default, find does not do a regex, but a Python glob file search. Might be worthy to try with `use_regex: true` **and** the filter to escape regex.

Comment: That was the answer.  It works with those two changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As counter-intuitive as it seems, an option is to actually enable a match via regex, with the parameter [`use_regex: true`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-use_regex) in combination with the usage of the [`regex_escape` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions).

The reason for this is pointed in the `pattern` parameter comment:

> One or more (shell or regex) patterns, which type is controlled by `use_regex` option.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#parameter-patterns*</sup>

And since the default of `use_regex` is `false`, the default behaviour would be to have a Shell pattern, which won't work well if you escape the character in a regex fashion.

So, you task ends up being:

```yaml
- name: collect paths for matching file
  find:
    paths: "{{ target_folder }}"
    patterns: "{{ filename | regex_escape }}"
    file_type: file
    recurse: true
    use_regex: true
  register: file_matches
```